# How to Convert ContentPage to WebForm using Visual Studio

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I've created some Asp.net pages as ContentPages and I got a request to change these pages as pop-ups instead of opening in the contents of a master page.

Is there a way to convert ContentPages to WebForms using Visual Studio built-in functionality or I must adjust the design of each manually ?

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/270385/convert-web-form-to-web-content-form-after-the-fact-net) may be relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if there is any inbuilt solution present (most probably NO) but one solution is to remove the master page section `MasterPageFile="~/some_name.master` from your page design section. Like,

Change this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/some_name.master" ...
```

To

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" ...
```